# Batch file reject blank entry not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I'm working through some code, and I need to reject a blank value but accept everything else; I can't see to do it... Does anyone have pointers, or could even fill it in for me...

```
:2
REM Basic account creation
echo Welcome to basic account creation.

REM user enters details
REM Username
echo Please Enter a Username
set /p username=
if "%username%"=="" (
goto 2
) else if not "%username%"=="" (
echo.
REM Real Name
echo Please enter your full name
set /p fullname=
echo.
REM Password
echo Please enter a password
set /p password=
echo.
)
REM Save to file
if exist %username%.log (
echo User name already exists, please enter a new user name to create an account, or return to the log in screen    
    goto 1
) else (
    echo %fullname% >> %username%.log
    echo %password% >> %username%.log
    echo %date% %time% >> %username%.log )
timeout /t 2 /nobreak > NUL
REM pause
if exist %username%.log (
echo. )
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
    goto 6
```

Comment: `%username%` is already a system variable. Call it something else.

Comment: @SomethingDark I need to make sure that the `%username%` variable is not blank, so I can't really call it something else, or can I? :/

Comment: My point is that it is impossible for a variable called `%username%` to be blank because it is reserved by Windows so you need to call it something else in order for your script to work correctly.

Comment: @SomethingDark Oh my gosh, you're a godsend!

Comment: I suppose I should actually post this as an answer, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%username%` is a preexisting system variable - it's the `xxx` in `C:\Users\xxx`.

You can change it for the duration of a script, but if you try to set it with `set /p` and then don't enter anything, the value will remain as its previous value of whatever your Windows username is.

You can work around this by changing the name of the `%username%` variable in your script to something else (see the output of `set` for a list of variables that exist already).

```
echo Please Enter a Username
set /p user_name=
if "%user_name%"=="" (
goto 2
) else if not "%user_name%"=="" (
echo.
```